# I'm not seeing "Publish" button in Amazon Lex Bot and all the tutorials' screenshots I'm finding don't align with my AWS Consoles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-lex, aws-pinpoint

Hello Stackoverflow Friends:

***Context**:*

1. **My goal** is to use Amazon Lex Bot to communicate via an **SMS text channel** using an **Amazon Pinpoint phone number** associated with my account. Users will send utterances via their native text client, i.e. the Messages application on their iPhone. It would reply to them in the same channel.
2. I did also want to include a 'middleware' layer of having a Lambda functions extract certain user utterances and or the user's phone number and store that in a Dynamo DB.

***Problem(s):***

1. I found [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/create-an-sms-chatbox-with-amazon-pinpoint-and-lex/) and I am blocked [Blockers listed below].
2. **There seems to be a disconnect between what I'm seeing in my AWS console and this tutorial (and documentation on AWS) as well as many video tutorials I'm seeing on YouTube - or I'm maybe doing something wrong?**
3. **Version 2?** I did observe that **my AWS Lex console that the URL that includes a "V2"** in the url ("https://console.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/home?region=us-east-1#bots") **I am not observing that "V2" in various instructors' videos that I've watched.** Which leads me to wonder if perhaps V2 is a new version of Lex and the documentation hasn't been released? [Here is a link to a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8zcgBLCm-E) done by one of the author's of the above linked tutorial and as you can see from the screenshot in his video it isn't /lexv2/ it is just /lex/.

**Screenshot from instructional video:**

[image]

**Screenshot from my AWS console:**

[image]

****Blockers / Questions:****

**1. [Tutorial says]**[1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/create-an-sms-chatbox-with-amazon-pinpoint-and-lex/) (in Step 1; `Request a long code for your country.`  When I do that - there is no focus / SMS capability is grayed out indicating [to me anyway] that the outcome / goal of this tutorial is not possible using a long code?
[image]

**Question**: As a workaround I selected a toll free number which had SMS capabilities. Is that permissible?

**2. In Step 2;** [the tutorial says](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/create-an-sms-chatbox-with-amazon-pinpoint-and-lex/), `Use the default IAM role` - there is no default, I selected.

[image]

**Question**: Is that a good path forward?

**3. Also in Step 2; [the tutorial says]**[1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/create-an-sms-chatbox-with-amazon-pinpoint-and-lex/), `When the bot finishes building, choose Publish. For Create an alias, enter Latest. Choose Publish.` - **I see no "Publish"** button and this is highly confusing as in many, many, many tutorials I've watched on YouTube the instructors have that button visible.

**Here is my screenshot of what I see [no "Publish" button]:**

[image]

**Here is Amazon document tutorial with a "Publish" button.**

[image]

**And here is a various tutorial I see online with a "Publish" button.**

[image]

**Question**: Did I miss a step (I did build it and test it and those controls to do that were on the bottom of the UI not on the top as all the tutorials I've found are. Is it possibly V2 of this Lex bot that has changed?

4. Assuming I can get past these blockers - in Step 3 of [the tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/create-an-sms-chatbox-with-amazon-pinpoint-and-lex/) it says, `Under Execution role, choose View the LexPinpointIntegrationDemoLambda role.`

**Question**: Not to be really dense but I have swirl on how to do that / where to do that. Can I get some direction / steps on exact steps to do that please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that the tutorial, which i also followed, is based on the Version 1 of the service and the console. On the lower left corner there is a button that says "Switch to V1 console"

After this you will get the same interface as the tutorial and you can continue with it.

Comment: Thank you @NicolasZ - I totally missed that link - I'm really surprised that AWS doesn't have documentation to match the version of the bot they default the user to. Thank you very, very, very much!!!!

Answer (score 2):

AWS does not have the **Publish** Button in the Lex V2. You will have to follow the following steps to publish your Bot in AWS Lex V2:

**1. Build the bot**
[image]

**2. Create the bot version**
[image]

[image]

**3. Create an Alias**
[image]

**3. Associate that version to a required alias**
[image]

**so once you create the bot version, it is considered published.**